# Drupal 7 : Is there a way to create a formatter for drupal email field

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view, drupal-views

Is there a way to create a formatter for drupal email field to decrypt when viewed in a view table.

I have tried to create a formatter for the same using the below code

```
function MYMODULE_field_formatter_info() {
  return array(
    'views_decrypt_field' => array(
      'label' => t('Decrypt this field'),
      'field types' => array('textfield'),
    ),
  );
}

function MYMODULE_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {
  $settings = $display['settings'];
  $element = array();
  if ($display['type'] == 'views_decrypt_field') {
    dsm($items);
  }
  return $element;
}
```

when I run this code, other fields with "textfield" type shows this formatter.
I am trying to create a generic formatter for all "text" type fields so that if they are encrypted then I can use this formatter in the view to decrypt the same.

**N.B:** The email field is not showing any formatter dropdown in the field settings in the VIEW.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use all function listing in this page : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/group/field_formatter/7.x

hook_field_formatter_info   =>  Expose Field API formatter types.

hook_field_formatter_info_alter => Perform alterations on Field API formatter types.

hook_field_formatter_prepare_view => Allow formatters to load information for field values being displayed.

hook_field_formatter_view =>    Build a renderable array for a field value.